# cloning azure devops git repository through visual studio 2017 throws error

Tags: git, azure, github, azure-devops, visual-studio-2017

I have created an organization in Azure DevOps. Under this organization, I created a project with private Git Repository in Azure DevOps.
Now When I try to clone this repository using Visual Studio 2017 I keep getting below mentioned error.

```
**Git failed with a fatal error.
unable to access 'https://dev.azure.com/organizationame/projectname/_git/projectname/': The requested URL returned error: 403**
```

Comment: one way to access git in azure devops is to use a personal access token. create an access token and type following address when cloning: https ://username@dev.azure.com/organizationame/projectname/_git/projectname/. enter your PAT when asked. Besides that, you could also use Git Credential Manager for windows: https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows

Comment: @MarioDietner Thank you for your response but I tried both options you mentioned in your reply and still I get the same error.

Comment: Can you try follow the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/clone?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio#clone-from-azure-repos--azure-devops-server authenticate to your organization using visual studio and then clone from there? Does this work?

Comment: @gold143 Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT I have tried options suggested by Mario but non of the suggestions worked. I am still struggling to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this in visual studio by the following steps ,every thing works well.

1.Connect to a project in Team Explorer

[image]

2.On the `Connect to a Project` page, select the repo you want to clone.

[image]

3.If a window pops up that requires credentials, enter your PAT and make sure your PAT has `Read, write & manage` permission in section `Code`.

[image]

4.The repository was cloned successfully.

[image]

If you have followed the steps but failed, please indicate at which step you got the error.